# Adding Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhook to WordPress, Problem with Rest Route?

Tags: php, rest-api, api, wp-api, microsoft

I am trying to implement an incoming webhook on my WordPress website to send a message to MS Teams when I receive a form submission. The message includes an `ActionCard` with a multiple choice input updating the status.

I have everything working in terms of sending the message to Teams and including the multiple choice input, but when I make a choice on the Teams message and click on the button to update the status, it's supposed to send the response back to my site, but I get an error message saying `"Failed to send - There was a problem submitting your changes. Try again in a minute."`

I have registered a custom rest route to capture the response which works fine when I use JavaScript `fetch()`, so I know the target url works; however, I cannot get it to work with this Teams response. Is there a different method I'm supposed to be using or what am I missing?

My class:

```php
class ERI_MICROSOFT_TEAMS {

    /**
     * The webhook for the MS Teams channel
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $webhook;


    /**
     * The option name where we store the chat messages
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $option_name;


    /**
     * Load when the site loads
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init() {

        // The webhook
        self::$webhook = 'https://[hidden]';

        // The option name
        self::$option_name = 'microsoft_teams_webhook';

        // Register custom API route for Teams
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', [ $this, 'register_route' ] );

    } // End init()


    /**
     * Process API $_POST request from Teams
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function process_request( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
        // Get the request body
        $message_data = $request->get_json_params();

        // Attempt to do something with it, let's just try to update a site option for now
        if ( update_option( self::$option_name, $message_data ) ) {

            // If it worked, then send success response and status
            $response = new WP_REST_Response( [ 'message' => 'Successful' ] );
            $response->set_status( 200 );
            return $response;

        // Otherwise respond with an error
        } else {
             return new WP_Error( 'invalid_request', 'Something went wrong', [ 'status' => 403 ] );
        }
    } // End process_request()


    /**
     * Register a custom API route
     * https://example.com/wp-json/eri/v1/msteams
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_route() {
        register_rest_route( 'eri/v1', '/msteams', [
             'methods'  => 'POST',
             'callback' => [ $this, 'process_request' ]
        ] );
    } // End register_route()


    /**
     * Send a message to MS Teams channel
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function send_msg( $form_id, $entry_id, $message, $name, $email, $phone = '(none)', $user_id = '(no user found)' ) {
        // Option prefix
        $pf = 'msteams_msg_';

        // Get the site name
        if ( get_option( $pf.'site_name' ) && get_option( $pf.'site_name' ) != '' ) {
            $site_name = get_option( $pf.'site_name' );
        } else {
            $site_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        }

        // Get the site image
        if ( get_option( $pf.'image' ) && get_option( $pf.'image' ) != '' ) {
            $image = get_option( $pf.'image' );
        } else {
            $image = 'https://example/wp-content/uploads/logo.png'; // Our Logo
        }

        // Get the accent color
        if ( get_option( $pf.'color' ) && get_option( $pf.'color' ) != '' ) {
            $color = get_option( $pf.'color' );
        } else {
            $color = '#FF0000'; // ERI Star
        }

        // Put the message card together
        $data = [
            '@type'      => 'MessageCard',
            '@context'   => 'https://schema.org/extensions',
            'summary'    => 'Website Help Desk Support Request',
            'themeColor' => $color,
            'title'      => 'New Support Request',
            'sections'   => [
                [
                    'activityTitle'    => $site_name,
                    'activitySubtitle' => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
                    'activityImage'    => $image,
                    'text'             => $message,
                    'facts'            => [
                        [
                            'name'  => 'Name: ',
                            'value' => $name
                        ],
                        [
                            'name'  => 'Email: ',
                            'value' => $email
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'potentialAction' => [
                [
                    '@type'   => 'OpenUri',
                    'name'    => 'Visit Site',
                    'targets' => [
                        [
                            'os'  => 'default',
                            'uri' => home_url()
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '@type'  => 'ActionCard',
                    'name'   => 'Update Status',
                    'inputs' => [
                        [
                            '@type'   => 'MultichoiceInput',
                            'id'      => 'status',
                            'title'   => 'Status',
                            'choices' => [
                                [
                                    'display' => 'Unresolved',
                                    'value'   => 'unresolved'
                                ],
                                [
                                    'display' => 'In Progress',
                                    'value'   => 'in_progress'
                                ],
                                [
                                    'display' => 'Resolved',
                                    'value'   => 'resolved'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'actions' => [ // WHERE I NEED HELP
                        [
                            '@type'  => 'HttpPOST',
                            'name'   => 'Update',
                            'target' => 'https://example.com/wp-json/eri/v1/msteams',
                            'body'   => '{{status.value}}'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ];

        // Encode
        $json_data = json_encode( $data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

        // Send it to discord
        $ch = curl_init( self::$webhook );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-type: application/json' ] );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

        $response = curl_exec( $ch );
        echo $response;
        curl_close( $ch );
    } // End send_msg()
}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#input-value-substitution) includes a JSON example, and I also tried using Postman to send just like their example shows, but I get the same error which makes me believe it's a problem with my rest route.

Comment: I posted an answer, but if the same problem persists, then, "*I also tried using Postman to send just like their example shows, but I get the same error*" - what are the request and response body and headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is the problem, but note that [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) returns a `false` if the the old and new option values are the **same**, so you should not simply do a `if ( update_option( self::$option_name, $message_data ) )` check.

So for example, you would instead do something like this:

```php
if ( get_option( self::$option_name ) === $message_data ||
    update_option( self::$option_name, $message_data )
) {
    // your code here - send a success response and status, etc.
}
```

Or maybe this:

```php
if ( get_option( self::$option_name ) === $message_data ) {
    $message = 'The old and new ' . self::$option_name . ' values are identical.';
    return [ 'message' => $message ];
} elseif ( update_option( self::$option_name, $message_data ) ) {
    return [ 'message' => 'Successful' ];
} // else, return a WP_Error instance
```

Additionally, just a note that you should *always* include set the [`permission_callback` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback), even for REST API routes that are intended to be public (and if it's public, then you can use `'permission_callback' => '__return_true',`).